# REST Data Source (OData) - 404: Not Found

Tags: oracle-apex

I have created OData API following [Getting Started with ASP.NET Core OData 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi-8/getting-started?tabs=net60%2Cvisual-studio-2022%2Cvisual-studio) and below are the results from browser

```
Request: http://localhost:5164/odata/pls/v1/Customers
Response: {"@odata.context":"http://localhost:5164/odata/pls/v1/$metadata#Customers","value":[{"Id":1,"Name":"Customer 1"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Customer 2"},{"Id":3,"Name":"Customer 3"}]}

Request: http://localhost:5164/odata/pls/v1/Customers(1)
Response: {"@odata.context":"http://localhost:5164/odata/pls/v1/$metadata#Customers/$entity","Id":1,"Name":"Customer 1"}
```

Then I followed [Oracle ODATA Connector](https://github.com/oracle/apex/tree/22.1/plugins/rest-source/odata-rest-apis) guideline to add the plugin. While creating REST Data Source, there is 404 error on pressing Discover button. Below are the details

[image]

[image]

[image]

No Auth is required here
[image]

Using **Apex 22.1.0** locally. `http://localhost:5164` is already added in ACL and `http://localhost:5164/Login` is being accessed successfully for custom login.

Please guide.

**Edit 1**
These are the results of the OData endpoint

```
http://localhost:5164/odata/pls/v1/Customers

{"@odata.context":"http://localhost:5164/odata/pls/v1/$metadata#Customers","value":[{"Id":1,"Name":"Customer 1"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Customer 2"},{"Id":3,"Name":"Customer 3"}]}

http://localhost:5164/odata/pls/v1/Customers(2)

{"@odata.context":"http://localhost:5164/odata/pls/v1/$metadata#Customers/$entity","Id":2,"Name":"Customer 2"}
```

[image]

Comment: If you get a HTTP-404, there is no ACL issue any more; the database was able to reach out and the REST URL Endpoint simply responded with HTTP-404 - Not found. Are you sure that all URL endpoints are indeed correct?

Comment: @Carsten Solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Urls and Paths were incorrect on `Remote Server` and `Settings` screens.
Below are the correct values against endpoint `http://localhost:5164/odata/pls/v1/Customers`

```
Base URL: http://localhost:5164/
URL Path Prefix: odata/pls/v1
Resource Path: Customers
```