# Apex 22.1 REST Data Source - 400: Bad request for ajax_dispatch_request

Tags: oracle-apex

Added a `REST Data Source` and below is its Test Result from Apex Dev Env itself. Requests from `Thunder Client` and `Swagger` are OK as well. But, there is 400 error on the application.

Any help please!

```
REST Data Source
    Name:           Directors 2
    REST Data Source Type:  Oracle REST Data Services
    Remote Server:      localhost
    Base URL:       http://localhost:5164/
    URL Path Prefix:    /Directors

LOV in Shared Component
    Name:           LOV_DIRECTORS
    Data Source:        REST Data Source
    REST Data Source:   Directors 2

Page item P3_NEW 
    Type:           Popup LOV
    List of Values
        Type:       Shared Component
        List of Values: LOV_DIRECTORS
```

[image]

[image]

Debug Messages are

APEX Version=22.1.0
SID=402
USER=APEX_PUBLIC_USER
ECID=d9Ts0zI_6CGd1rFN70j8JQ
PROXY_USER=ORDS_PUBLIC_USER
INSTANCE=1
CGI: PATH_INFO = /wwv_flow.ajax?p_context=pibasworld%2Frest-data-source%2F8967875288500
POST http://localhost:8080/ords
REMOTE_USER=APEX_PUBLIC_USER
APEX_LISTENER_VERSION=22.2.0.r1721758
REFERER=http://localhost:8080/
Error: Ajax call returned server error ORA-20999: REST Data Source returned an HTTP error: HTTP 400: Bad request for ajax_dispatch_request.

- is_internal_error: true
- is_common_runtime_error: false
- apex_error_code: APEX.AJAX_SERVER_ERROR
- ora_sqlcode: -20999
- ora_sqlerrm: ORA-20999: REST Data Source returned an HTTP error: HTTP 400: Bad request
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_NATIVE_ITEM", line 3644
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_NATIVE_ITEM", line 3201
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC_WEB_SRC", line 2232
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC_WEB_SRC", line 2002
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC_WEB_SRC", line 1918
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC_WEB_SRC", line 608
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC_WEB_SRC", line 1913
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC_WEB_SRC", line 2198
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC_WEB_SRC", line 2249
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC", line 830
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC", line 1124
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_LOV", line 1741
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_NATIVE_ITEM", line 3132
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_NATIVE_ITEM", line 3629
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_NATIVE_ITEM", line 7309
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_PLUGIN~
- error_backtrace: ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_NATIVE_ITEM", line 3644
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_NATIVE_ITEM", line 3201
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC_WEB_SRC", line 2232
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC_WEB_SRC", line 2002
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC_WEB_SRC", line 1918
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC_WEB_SRC", line 608
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC_WEB_SRC", line 1913
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC_WEB_SRC", line 2198
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC_WEB_SRC", line 2249
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC", line 830
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC", line 1124
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_LOV", line 1741
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_NATIVE_ITEM", line 3132
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_NATIVE_ITEM", line 3629
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_NATIVE_ITEM", line 7309
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_PLUGIN", line 2455
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_PLUGIN", line 4133
  ORA-06~
- component: APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_ITEMS P3_NEW (2346920829881307)

Comment: The error message references a page item "P3_NEW" - but you don't mention that anywhere ? How is that page item used in this context ?

Comment: @KoenLostrie `P3_NEW` is a Popup LOV using a shared LOV based on that REST Data Source. Added definitions in the question.

Comment: I've seen that you created the REST Data Source as of the "ORDS" type. Is your REST API really an ORDS REST API, or is it something else? If you're really using an ORDS REST Module here, change the REST Data Source type to "SImple HTTP".
If that does not help, a LEVEL9 debug of the error page would be helpful - that will show all the details of the HTTP request which APEX made, and you should be able to quickly see where things go wrong.

Comment: @Carsten Solved.

Comment: @Carsten can you please help on this as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76387741/rest-data-source-odata-404-not-found

Comment: @Carsten Please post your answer. Why Apex was able to fetch data as Test Result which made me think all is ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen that you created the REST Data Source as of the "ORDS" type. Is your REST API really an ORDS REST API, or is it something else? If you're really using an ORDS REST Module here, change the REST Data Source type to "SImple HTTP". If that does not help, a LEVEL9 debug of the error page would be helpful - that will show all the details of the HTTP request which APEX made, and you should be able to quickly see where things go wrong.

The reason why this was not flagged by the "Test" operation is that "Test" does not append any parameters to the URL.  However, when you use the REST API in a report, APEX appends "offset" and "limit" parameters to the URL for ORDS REST Sources, as APEX "knows" that ORDS will then return only the exactly requested rows. Your REST API however, just coughed on these and rejected with HTTP-400.